# meaning of the word "that" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of the word “that” in this context?

It is from this [video](https://youtu.be/QIJwyY_JyQU). It is at 3 minute and 36 second. Here is the context:

> But just like HIV, herpes has multiple strains, so there is still a lot of risk of transmission. **That** and no you may not have sex with me, I did not consent. My intent is to educate.

I cannot get what the host was referring to. Besides I am confused by the use of the words *and* and *no* after it.

Comment: **that** can refer back to the gist of an earlier statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to back up a bit more. She's talking about the following comment [censorship mine]:

> I have herpes and Doe has herpes. Means I can **[censored]** her bareback

This comment implies that since they both have herpes, he may have unprotected sex with her, to which she replies

> just like HIV, herpes has multiple strains, so there is still a lot of risk of transmission. That, and no: you may not have sex with me, I did not consent. My intent is to educate.

In this case, she is stating that he is wrong to make the assumption, and gives reasons why he is wrong.

**That** refers to the *"risk of transmission"* from the previous sentence. That's Reason 1.

*"I did not consent"* is Reason 2.

*"you may not have sex with me"* is basically "you're wrong". (having the *no:* in front further emphasizes that he is wrong)

And the **and** links it all together.

The *"That, and no:"* could have been replaced by **Also** and kept the same meaning.

> [...]there is still a lot of risk of transmission. **Also**, you may not have sex with me, I did not consent.

Answer (score 0):

In the video, the host is explaining why having the same sexually transmitted infection  as a partner is not a justification for not using protection during intercourse. This is a result of a comment online that mentions this and also asks to have sex with the host.

The host has multiple things to say about the comment in question:

1. There are different strains of the same sexually transmitted infection, which still can be transmitted between partners with the same infection.
2. She does not agree to have sex with the commenter.

So she states

> But just like HIV, herpes has multiple strains, so there is still a lot of risk of transmission. **That** and no you may not have sex with me, I did not consent. My intent is to educate.

She is outlining her response to the commenter. ***That*** is referring to the first thing she has to say (about the different strains of infection).